# How to Bulk Insert 5.5M records in mongodb through django model with in small time?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, dataframe, bulkinsert

It took me around **6.5 to 7 hours** in inserting bulk records from pandas dataframe of **5.5M records** to my **mongodb database** through **django model** with **12-GB RAM**. Below is the code for raised query. I want to make it faster to around **30 mins to 1 hour** time, Is it possible ?

```
# Split DF

listDf = []
listDf = split_dataframe(completeDF02)

## This completeDF02 is the full dataframe having 5.5M records, So I split it with having 0.1M record in one batch in listDf list

for item in listDf:
    df_records = item.to_dict('records')
    model_instances = [MyModel(
        Field1=record['Field1'],
        Field2=record['Field2'],
        Field3=record['Field3'],
        Field4=record['Field4'],
        Field5=record['Field5'],
        Field6=record['Field6'],
        Field7=record['Field7'],
        Field8=record['Field8'],
        Field9=record['Field9'],
        Field10=record['Field10'],
        Field11=record['Field11'],
        Field12=record['Field12'],
        Field13=record['Field13'],
        Field14=record['Field14'],
        Field15=record['Field15'],
        Field16=record['Field16'],
        Field17=record['Field17'],
        Field18=record['Field18'],
        Field19=record['Field19'],
        Field20=record['Field20'],
        Field21=record['Field21'],
        Field22=record['Field22'],
        Field23=record['Field23'],
        Field24=record['Field24'],
        Field25=record['Field25']
    ) for record in df_records]
    
    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(model_instances)
```

Is there an alternate way of doing bulk inserts to get more efficiency with speed ? If yes, then please let me know.

Comment: That has nothing to do with django i guess it is the mongodb that you have to configure to increase the speed.

Comment: So, there is nothing wrong with that approach ? Can you please elaborate how can I configure mongodb in a way that it can give efficient speed.

Comment: Not very programmatic, but I had about 3.5M records that I exported with `DataFrame.to_json` and then I just used `Compass` to import the entire JSON into a database collection.  It went reasonably quick.

Comment: I have tested your way too, But it is taking same amount of time.

Comment: Can you identify the bottleneck? ... IO write speed? ... running out of memory (swap usage?)? ... CPU limited?  I have 16GB of RAM and write to a SSD, but I don't know how significant that is.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is/are some indexing going on that limits document insertion rate. If you delete all indexes before inserting, and then recreate them when done, is the overall time reduced?

Comment: No, Overall time remains constant.

Comment: Is there any validation happening?  I recently piped a ~8GB (3M docs) of JSON through `sed` (minor formatting/cleanup), `jq` ("_id" insertion), and then `mongoimport`.  It completed in about 20 minutes.  I created the indexes later and didn't use any validation.

Comment: Yes there is validation happening, but not for each record, Validation is only for the file and its schema, It gets completed in max 3 mins. After that all of this is record insertion in db through django model.

Comment: Where is the time being spent, in `model_instances` creation or `bulk_create`?